# 'Undo' in unload event of a subform

Tags: vba, ms-access

I wanted the user to confirm the changes he made on a record, so I added 'Save' and 'Discard' buttons to my form. Discard button runs `DoCmd.RunCommand(acCmdUndo)` which works fine. I also added this line to Form_Unload event of my form to undo unsaved changes before quit, which also works fine.

The problem is when I use this form (let's say form1) as a subform in another (main) form. When I hit the close (X) button of the main form, vba gives this error under Form_Unload event of form1:

> Run time error '2046': The command or action 'Undo' isn't available now.

I also tried `Me.Undo`, but apparently it's not working in Unload event at all.

So my specific question is how can I discard the unsaved changes of a record in a subform, on the unload or exit event of the main form.

Comment: If you run `Undo` from the main form does it affect the subform like you want?

Comment: I added `DoCmd.RunCommand(acCmdUndo)` to the unload event of the main form, and it gives the same error 2046.

Comment: I always disable X close and provide custom buttons for closing forms. Quite possibly when you click main form X close the subform record is committed to table and UNDO is no longer possible. Even if it is, would probably have to first set focus back to subform before executing UNDO.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that when X button is pressed everything gets saved; and no Undo will be available. `Form_Unload` is too late to intercept the saving action. `Form_BeforeUpdate` can be used instead.